# Name of PCB termination

Tags: pcb, termination

Whoever knows how that circle terminations called (part number)?
[image]

Comment: It is a test point for hooking on probes.

Comment: I've sometimes seen it informally called a 'hairpin', though 'through hole test point' would be better.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Keystone [part #5000](http://keyelco.com/userAssets/file/M65p56.pdf) through-hole test point.

[image]

On early board spins, I like to put a footprint for at least one for a scope probe ground (usually black, but red is easier to see). They can be omitted in production as they are not particularly cheap. You can get SMT ones that are machine installable but they don't work as well and I don't think they are very appropriate.